# The object of type 'BallMovement' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I checked all over SO but couldn't find an answer that worked (or at least that I understood how to implement).

I just started Unity not too long ago and I'm trying to make a Pong clone. The game work great on the first run, but when a player wins and it switches to scene 2, then you press the Play Again button and go back to scene 1 (gameplay scene) I get this error while trying to play:

[image]

heres my Start method for the problematic class.

```cs
public class BallMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D ball;
    Vector2 vel;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        float posY = Random.Range(-150, 150);
        ball = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Ball").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        transform.localPosition = new Vector2(-19, posY);
        vel.x = 250;
        vel.y = -150;
        ball.velocity = vel;

        GameStateManager.PlayerScored += Start;
    }
...
```

sorry for asking such a dumb/ vague question but I'm seriously stuck, I've been working on this pong clone for 8 hours and I managed to cross every hurdle on my own besides this

Comment: You should post the error as text, besides that, showing the class doesn't make it any clearer, it means you are accessing an object that does not exist, the object from where you are trying to call the method is null, maybe a good time to train your debugging skills.

Comment: Post text as text. Not as an image: images of text, pose a big accessibility problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mmm I think your bug probably lies on this line:

```
GameStateManager.PlayerScored += Start;
```

I'm going to guess that `GameStateManager` is somehow surviving across scene loads, whether that's a GameObject that doesn't destroy or a ScriptableObject or something.

What I think is happening is that you're adding a delegate to your `PlayerScored` event and then that event isn't getting reset when you're changing scenes. When you come back to the scene the second time, that *instance* of the `BallMovement` class has been deleted, and when that event fires you get the error `The object of type 'BallMovement' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it`.

Another kind of concerning thing I see with this is that you're having a method add itself to an event - when you run `Start` the first time, on the Unity `Start` callback, you add yourself to the `PlayerScored` event.

Then, when `PlayerScored` fires, you add `Start` to the `PlayerScored` event *a second time*. Then the second time `PlayerScored` triggers it fires `Start` twice, so you add it twice, and the third trigger now has four events to call. Duplicates are allowed in event invocation lists so you'll trigger `Start` for every time it's in the `PlayerScored` list, and every time it's called it adds itself again.

The way around this would be to move that functionality out of start, and to remove the delegate from the event when the GameObject is destroyed. Consider the following instead:

```
public class BallMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D ball;
    Vector2 vel;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GameStateManager.PlayerScored += OnPlayerScored;
        OnPlayerScored(); // Fire this once on Start to get everything setup!
    }

    void OnPlayerScored()
    {
        float posY = Random.Range(-150, 150);
        ball = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Ball").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        transform.localPosition = new Vector2(-19, posY);
        vel.x = 250;
        vel.y = -150;
        ball.velocity = vel;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        GameStateManager.PlayerScored -= OnPlayerScored;
    }

// ...
```

Comment: I actually did have an OnDestroy method removing the delegate from the event as you showed, so I just added the Start stuff to a new method as u showed and it didnt work - at first. I then realized that I also made the same mistake in other classes, so I made sure to always destroy the delegate when I assigned it and it worked! many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems you Delete/ Dispose the `BallMovement` class. I assume this is because you Delete/ Dispose the ball, and don't create the new ball with the `BallMovement` class/ script.